# Edit your query to include at least one column that identifies specific devices, users, or mailboxes

Tags: kql

I need help in Kusto query language.I have a query created in advanced hunting that aggregates impossible travel alerts and excludes our external adress.

```
AlertEvidence
| where Title == "Impossible travel activity"
| summarize Adresy = make_list_if(RemoteIP, isnotempty(RemoteIP)), Konto = make_set(AccountName) by AlertId, Timestamp
| where not((array_length(Adresy)<=2) and Adresy has_any ("*.*.*.*"))
```

The problem is i get following error: Edit your query to include at least one column that identifies specific devices, users, or mailboxes.

I wanted to project AccountName column but it is impossible. When I use make_set from AccountName it becomes invisible for the system. It highlights me this column as unknown. How can I turn this query into detection rule? Can I unpack somehow this value from the table and use it in project at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a column to indicate the user associated with the `AccountName`. Consider joining the `AlertEvidence table` with another table that contains user information.

For example, you can join the `AlertEvidence table` with the `SigninLogs table` to get the user associated with the `AccountName`.

Below is sample query:

```html
let impossibleTravelAlerts = AlertEvidence
| where Title == "Impossible travel activity"
| summarize Adresy = make_list_if(RemoteIP, isnotempty(RemoteIP)), Konto = make_set(AccountName) by AlertId, Timestamp
| where not((array_length(Adresy)<=2) and Adresy has_any ("*.*.*.*"));
let userSignins = SigninLogs
| where ResultType == 0 // successful sign-ins only
| summarize LastSignin = max(TimeGenerated) by UserPrincipalName;
impossibleTravelAlerts
| join kind=innerunique userSignins on Konto
| project Timestamp, UserPrincipalName, Adresy
```